# Create a Dynamic List of Values

Tags: oracle, oracle-apex, oracle-apex-5.1

I have a function that returns an Array of codes (NUMBER).

```
select GET_USER_OFFICE_CODES(10) FROM DUAL;
```

returns

```
DB.OFFICE_CODES(3,4,5,6,7,8,9)
```

Ultimately I would like to create a LOV that uses this function in an APEX 5.1 application.

For example,

```
select office_code, id 
from offices where ID IN (select GET_USER_OFFICE_CODES(10) FROM DUAL);
```

Obviously, I am having trouble with datatypes.

Can someone help me massage the results in SQL so that I can just do the following in SQL?

```
select * 
from offices 
where ID IN (select GET_USER_OFFICE_CODES(10) FROM DUAL);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It would have helped if you described what the function exactly does. I'm now just guessing.

Function:

```
SQL> create or replace function f_test(par_in in number)
  2    return sys.odcinumberlist
  3  is
  4    l_arr sys.odcinumberlist := sys.odcinumberlist();
  5  begin
  6    l_arr.extend;
  7    l_arr(l_arr.last) := 10;
  8    l_arr.extend;
  9    l_arr(l_arr.last) := 20;
 10    return l_arr;
 11  end;
 12  /

Function created.
```

What does it return?

```
SQL> select f_test(10) from dual;

F_TEST(10)
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
ODCINUMBERLIST(10, 20)
```

How to use it in Apex?

```
SQL> select deptno d,
  2         dname r
  3  from dept d
  4  where d.deptno in (select * from table(f_test(10)));

         D R
---------- --------------
        10 ACCOUNTING
        20 RESEARCH

SQL>
```

Comment: Thanks!  You nailed it for me.  I simply was not finding the keyword "table" in my searches that you document perfectly above.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that `DB.OFFICE_CODES` is a collection defined in the SQL scope then you can use the `MEMBER OF` operator:

```sql
select * 
from offices 
where ID MEMBER OF GET_USER_OFFICE_CODES(10);
```

Which outputs:

> ```
> ID | LOCATION  
> -: | :---------
>  3 | Location 3
>  4 | Location 4
>  5 | Location 5
>  6 | Location 6
>  7 | Location 7
>  8 | Location 8
>  9 | Location 9
> ```

Assuming your schema is called `DB` and this is an example of your setup:

```sql
CREATE TYPE DB.OFFICE_CODES IS TABLE OF NUMBER;

CREATE FUNCTION GET_USER_OFFICE_CODES(
  value IN INT
) RETURN DB.OFFICE_CODES
IS
BEGIN
  -- Do something to get your values.
  RETURN DB.OFFICE_CODES(3,4,5,6,7,8,9);
END;
/
```

Then, if you have the `offices` table:

```sql
CREATE TABLE offices ( id, location ) AS
SELECT LEVEL, 'Location ' || LEVEL FROM DUAL CONNECT BY LEVEL <= 10;
```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=00af5dedcc03d9ff31da47f8c62b26c9)*